How to mirror GitHub pull requests on Gitlab?
Since pull requests are not part of git but of Github, is there a solution to mirror Github pull requests in gitlab via branches?
I'm using gitlab's default solution (pull) but with this solution I can't see github's pull request commits.
Only the gitlab solution.
Not finding much on the subject.

Can you elaborate on what you want to see and what you mean by "pull request commits" -- if the source branch is part of the same repository, you should be able to mirror those branches, right?

According to the Gitlab documentation, you can import Github projects to Gitlab. This feature is available with the Free, Premium and Ultimate version of Gitlab.
Under the list of Imported data, it's mentionned:

The following items of a project are imported:

...

Pull requests.

...



